# iOS - Parse cloud match user according to its location

Tags: ios, parse-platform

## I'm working on taxi booking service and using Parse as a backend.

**-Client adding new Order (which contains pick up point coordinates and destination point coordinates), and cloud code should match the closest Driver (parameter 'currentLocation') to the pick point.**

**-Then system offering an Order to the Driver, if Driver not responding or declining an Order, system should find another Driver.**

What algorithm should I have on cloud code side? I think I should have anything like matching session, but have no idea of doing this yet. Also: driver should accept order in 2mins, or order will be declined and will go to another Driver. Thank you!

Comment: There is no predefined algorithm for this particular case yet. You have to make it up by starting to write some code. That will be the algorithm.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Two main issues I faced now: how to compare and find closest driver (not a big problem). Second: how to get notified this driver. Can I use push notification and pass order data directly to this driver, and fire an action on driver's device?. Thank you @Elis Byberi